# jQuery images with fadeIn() don't load when page is cached or accessed via back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

At the beginning of my script, I have:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('img.thumbnail').hide().load( function() {
    jQuery('img.thumbnail').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Which nicely fades in all the thumbnails on the page as they are loaded.  However, when I access the page for a second time (when it is cached), or when I press the back button in the browser, the images stay hidden and never appear.  I have to manually refresh the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ensnare - you should put in a simple `alert('hello');` or `console.log('fired');` in your `$().ready(...` to ensure that it is being executed when you load up the page from cache or through the back button.

Comment: I updated the answer below, let me know if that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, since `.load()` [may not fire on all browsers when fetching from cache](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('img.thumbnail').hide().each(function() {
     if (this.complete)
        $(this).fadeIn();
     else
        $(this).load( function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it to a `$(document).ready()` statement?  Then it should run whenever the page is done loading.